# How can I connect to my Wi-Fi AP at 1300 Mbps link speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, 802.11ac, iperf3

I have a [TP-Link Archer C80](https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c80/#specifications) that's advertised as a AC1900 MU-MIMO router. It doesn't support Wi-Fi 6 (802.11ax) but they advertise Wi-Fi speeds as:

> 5 GHz: 1300 Mbps (802.11ac)
>
> 2.4 GHz: 600 Mbps (802.11n)

Now I have 3 Wi-Fi 6 (802.11ax) capable devices (not Wi-Fi 6E but just 6).

- My laptop (MSI GE75 Raider 9SG) has a **Killer(R) Wireless-AC 1550i Wireless Network Adapter (9560NGW) 160MHz** WLAN adapter
- My Asus PN50 Mini PC has a **Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz** WLAN adapter
- My Xiaomi Mi 11x Pro supports **802.11a/b/g/n/ac/ax**

I'm not sure about MU-MIMO support but the [Mi 11i](https://www.mi.com/global/product/mi-11i/specs) specs page (another alias for the Mi 11x Pro) state that it has **2x2 MIMO，8x8 Sounding for MU-MIMO**

For the laptop and Mini PC, as far as I can tell MU-MIMO is supported but there's no additional info I could find about that.

All 3 devices connect to the Archer C80 over Wi-Fi at a maximum link speed of **867 Mbps** and when I run iPerf3 tests to confirm the actual speeds I'm getting, the maximum speeds I've seen are around **397 Mbps** (with GE75 connected to Ethernet as the iPerf3 server and Mi 11x Pro connected to Archer C80 over Wi-Fi on the 5GHz band as the iPerf3 client)

The iPerf3 command I ran on the client (Mi 11x Pro) was this:

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.0.100 -i 0 -t 60 -P 2
```

And to test for reverse connection speeds:

```
iperf3 -c 192.168.0.100 -i 0 -t 60 -P 2 -R
```

My question is this:

**Is it possible to have any or all of these devices connect to Archer C80 at 1300 Mbps link speed and get iPerf3 results that reflect that?**

I don't expect to get the full 1300 Mbps speeds but somewhere close to 1000 Mbps so it's equivalent to or slightly better than gigabit Ethernet speeds maybe.

Comment: Different wireless clients will negotiate different link speeds with the wireless router, based on the wireless modes, distance, and noise level (the level of interference from other wireless transmissions). Are the tested devices placed right next to each other? Do they support this speed when connected via Ethernet? Do other devices also connect to the router and may slow others? Is the router set to channel width 80MHz for 5GHz? Remember also that WiFi is half duplex, so bandwidth is shared for transmission and reception as both can't happen at the same time.

Comment: @harrymc The iPerf3 tests were done with the client (Mi 11x Pro) around 5-6 feet away the router and the server (MSI GE75) connected via Ethernet. All 3 devices can achieve the full 1 Gbps speeds (actually around 960 Mbps) when connected to Ethernet. It's a gigabit router with Ethernet speeds only upto 1 Gbps. It's the WLAN speeds that it claims go upto 1300 Mbps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a 1300 Mbps link at 80 MHz channel width, you need 3 spatial streams. I'm not aware of any client device offering that.

With 2 spatial streams, you'll get a 867 Mbps link at best.

User data throughput is lower still, of course. You won't get 1000 Mbps with this setup, even with 3 spatial streams.

Comment: Thank you. I was also recently informed that I may need a router capable of setting channel width to 160 MHz. With that, I should be able to connect to the router at 1300 Mbps with a client with 2 spatial streams? Is that also correct? Either a client with 3 spatial streams or a router capable of setting channel width to 160 MHz?

Comment: I found this router that seems to be able to do 160 MHz: [Archer AX50](https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-ax50/#specifications). Would I be able to get 1300 Mbps or better link speeds (they advertise 2402 Mbps) with it?

Comment: Maybe? You’d need Wi-Fi 6 clients, of course. At 80 MHz channel width, I have 1200 Mbps link speed, resulting in 609 Mbps throughput. My suggestion is to just give up and stick with what works. Way easier on the wallet.

Comment: As for a client with 3 spatial streams, I found [this link](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/deployment/dep2ac3e3b51/web) on the Wi-Fi specs of Apple laptops and according to it, MacBook Pro models from 2017–2019 have 3x3 MIMO. It just so happens to be that I have an Intel based 16-inch 2019 MacBook Pro and I just checked the **Wi-Fi Tx Rate** I get with it when connected to the 5GHz band and it is indeed 1300 Mbps! That clears up a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I think I'll hold off on a good Wi-Fi 6 router until I can actually find a decent one for a good price with with minimal misleading advertising but Wi-Fi 7 might be out by that time so I'll just take the stronger signal that this one affords me and also 2x bandwidth on the 2.4 GHz band compared to my old router. However, your answer really helped me understand Wi-Fi a little better. Thanks.

Comment: Screenshot of my **MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019)** connected to the router at **1300 Mbps** link speed for anyone interested: [imgur link](https://i.imgur.com/Qi7QZMk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing the difference between theoretical and real-world speed. Reasons can vary and are often not simple to determine.

from [Signalboosters](https://www.signalboosters.com/blog/the-80211ac-wifi-standard-explained/):

> Forbes states that the fastest real-world 802.11ac speeds recorded are
> around 720 Mbps (0.72 Gbps). In contrast, the maximum speed recorded
> for 802.11n was 240 Mbps (0.24 Gbps).

from [Lifewire](https://www.lifewire.com/how-fast-is-a-wifi-network-816543#toc-theoretical-vs-actual-network-speeds) - see the article for a comparison table:

> An 802.11b network typically operates no faster than about 50 percent
> of its theoretical peak, around 5.5 Mbps. The 802.11a and 802.11g
> networks usually run no faster than 20 Mbps. Even though 802.11n rates
> at 600 Mbps compared to wired Fast Ethernet at 100 Mbps, the Ethernet
> connection can often outperform 802.11n in real-world usage.

And from [CenturyLink](https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/wireless/which-frequency-should-you-use.html):

> **Theoretical speed** is the maximum speed that is usually listed on the
> box. This can be misleading, because even if all conditions are ideal,
> you may not reach this speed all the time. It's important to
> understand that:
>
> - It is a combined total for both uploading and downloading
> - It is calculated based on a  single device being connected to the network
> - It does not consider wireless overhead, interference and distance
>
> **Real-world speed** accounts for factors like:
>
> - Sharing bandwidth with other devices connected to your WiFi network
> - Interference from physical obstacles
> - Interference from electronics
> - Interference from nearby WiFi networks or wireless devices
> - Signal loss resulting from the distance between your device and your wireless router

So, the speeds you measure are absolutely nominal.  People who have [reviewed the TP-Link Archer C80](https://www.google.com/search?q=TP-Link%20Archer%20C80%20review) have found similar results. The speed you measure with iPerf will furthermore depend on <s>your ISP, your network topology, and how far away their closest server is.</s> your Network topology.

Comment: For clarity, are you saying a Wi-Fi 6 router that supports 802.11ax would have been a better choice (better as in it may have faster real-world speeds) compared to the fastest 802.11ac router?

Comment: Also, how would iPerf results depend on my ISP? My intention with the iPerf test is to determine the Wi-Fi speed (as in how fast can clients connected to the same local Wi-Fi network transmit/receive to/from each other) not my Internet connection speed.

Comment: I plan to do another test tomorrow with all interference eliminated (away from as many other routers and wireless devices as possible) to see if I can get better speeds that way and will update my question with the results but it seems misleading to advertise a router with 1300 Mbps WLAN speeds when the much older Archer C50 that's advertised as a AC1200 router [867 Mbps (802.11ac)] gives me about the same performance (with negligible speed difference). I'm referring to the WLAN local network speed and not the Internet speed. I expect no difference in Internet speed with either router.

Comment: Google for "802.11ax real world speed" or for "802.11ac real world speed".

Comment: Sorry, ISP doesn't influence. My error. Don't know Iperf well enough

Comment: No worries. Thanks